# How can I filter an Iterable based upon a Predicate?

Tags: java, java-8, predicate, iterable

I want to do a string list filter function using an `Iterable<String>` and a predicate to select the strings to keep, the other ones must be removed from the list, but I'm not understating how I do the remove.

```
static <T> Iterable<T> select(Iterable<T> it, Predicate<T> pred) {
    for (T s: it) {
        if (pred.test(s)==false) {
            // what to do here?
        }
    }
    return ...;
}
```

For this input:

```
{"a","","b",""}
```

I expect

```
{"a","b"}
```

Comment: Pet peeve: `pred.test(s)==false` is bad style. Use `!pred.test(s)`

Comment: Ty for the tip!

Comment: BTW, the method you want already exists within Guava: [`Iterables.filter`](https://google.github.io/guava/releases/21.0/api/docs/com/google/common/collect/Iterables.html#filter-java.lang.Iterable-com.google.common.base.Predicate-). Check their implementation.

Answer (score 5):

An `Iterable` represents the capability to provide an `Iterator` on request. So, to decorate an existing iterable with a filtering logic, you have to implement the decorating `Iterator`.

```
static <T> Iterable<T> select(Iterable<T> it, Predicate<T> pred) {
    return () -> new Iterator<T>() {
        Iterator<T> sourceIterator = it.iterator();
        T current;
        boolean hasCurrent;

        @Override
        public boolean hasNext() {
            while(!hasCurrent) {
                if(!sourceIterator.hasNext()) {
                    return false;
                }
                T next = sourceIterator.next();
                if(pred.test(next)) {
                    current = next;
                    hasCurrent = true;
                }
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public T next() {
            if(!hasNext()) throw new NoSuchElementException();
            T next = current;
            current = null;
            hasCurrent = false;
            return next;
        }
    };
}
```

which you may test via

```
List<String> original = new ArrayList<>();
Collections.addAll(original, "foo", "bar", "baz");
Iterable<String> filter = select(original, s -> s.startsWith("b"));
System.out.println(String.join(", ", filter));
original.removeIf(s -> !s.endsWith("r"));
System.out.println(String.join(", ", filter));
```

The biggest challenge when implementing such an `Iterator`, is to provide the two methods `hasNext` and `next` with the correct semantics, without any guaranty regarding how the caller will invoke them, i.e. you can not assume that it will never invoke `hasNext()` twice nor that `next()` will always be invoked with a preceding `hasNext()`.

The same logic can be implemented much easier using the Stream API:

```
static <T> Iterable<T> select(Iterable<T> it, Predicate<T> pred) {
    return () -> StreamSupport.stream(it.spliterator(), false)
        .filter(pred).iterator();
}
```

Comment: guava solved this complicated pattern internally using an `AbstractIterator` that would just have one `computeNext` method IIRC; pretty much the same idea as `tryAdvance`. This allows them to have `Iterators::filter` easily implemented.

Comment: I think I'd prefer advancing the source iterator on `next() ` rather in `hasNext() `, then storing the "next" value or `null` if none is available. Should reduce complexity a bit as well.

Comment: @daniu that doesn't help with the usual use case of `hasNext()` being called before `next()` and being required to give the right answer.

Comment: I might not have explained properly, this is what I meant: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56399526/2837741

Comment: I just realized that the behavior of your solution (mine too) that I wouldn't expect the behavior that if the underlying collection is modified - as in your test case -, this results in a change in the `Iterable` returned before the change.

Comment: @daniu that’s intentional behavior; it’s decorating an iterable or creating a filtered *view* of it. Just like Guava’s `Iterables.filter`, as mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56365595/how-can-i-filter-an-iterable-based-upon-a-predicate/56393939?noredirect=1#comment99334452_56365595) does. If you want a snapshot rather than a view, there’s no way around collecting the elements, like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56365659/2711488) does.

Answer (score 1):

Since any `Collection` is `Iterable`, just add the qualified items to a new collection and return it later:

```
static <T> Iterable<T> select(Iterable<T> it, Predicate<T> pred) {
    Collection<T> collection = new ArrayList<>();
    for (T s: it) {
        if (!pred.test(s)) {
            collection.add(s);
        }
    }
    return collection;
}
```

Few insights:

- The `pred.test(s)==false` expression shall be rather simplified to `!pred.test(s)`
- The whole content of method could be shortened using [java-stream](/questions/tagged/java-stream) in this way:

  ```
  static <T> Iterable<T> select(Iterable<T> it, Predicate<T> pred) {
      return StreamSupport.stream(it.spliterator(), false)
          .filter(pred)
          .collect(Collectors.toList());
  }
  ```

Comment: It's one solution, but not an efficient one. Better to implement a custom itera**tor** which is capable of skipping items - that's what Guava's implementation does.

Comment: In the exercise, they tell me that the function must retrieve an iterable and not a collection

Comment: @GFAA All `Collection`s **are** `Iterable`s. He assigns to `Collection<T>` so that he can add items to it.

Comment: So instead of collection and iterable, i can retrieve a List or an Arraylist?

Comment: @Michael Yes, there are lots of ways. I prefer to not import Guava just for this use-case. However, it is a good practice to "inspire" with an already existing implementation :)

Comment: @GFAA: You can do `Collection<T> collection = new ArrayList<>();` or `List<T> collection = new ArrayList<>();` or even `ArrayList<T> collection = new ArrayList<>();` (I recommend the highest abstraction). You cannot use `Iterable` directly since it doens't have a method `add` and is only for the reading.

Comment: @Nikolas Yeah, I know but I'm at the beginning of java and I don't think my teacher wants us to use Collection or Java-Stream yet, I understand that code must be kept the more abstract it can be. TY for the answer, now I fully got it.

Comment: @GFAA: That's why I provided two ways - the first one to fully satisfy your needs and the second one if it would be on my own.

Comment: It’s correct that `pred.test(s)==false` can be simplified to `!pred.test(s)`, but neither is correct when the predicate is supposed to specify which elements *to keep*.

Comment: A major advantage of Iterable/Iterator is they they can stream the data in from a large data source, for example.  This solution is not optimal in that it requires bulk loading all of the data into the Collection.  Building an Iterator that applies the Predicate to each item as it is accessed would be much preferred.

Answer (score 1):

First wrap your `Iterable<T>` into `Stream<T>`:

- Plain Java:

  ```
  StreamSupport.stream(it.spliterator(), false)
  ```
- [Guava](https://static.javadoc.io/com.google.guava/guava/21.0/com/google/common/collect/Streams.html#stream-java.util.Iterator-)

  ```
  Streams.stream(it)
  ```
- [StreamEx](https://amaembo.github.io/streamex/javadoc/one/util/streamex/StreamEx.html#of-java.util.Iterator-)

  ```
  StreamEx.of(it.iterator())
  ```

Then filter it by your `Predicate<T>` :

```
...
stream.filter(pred.negate())
...
```

And finally return `Iterable<T>`:

- as `lambda` :

  ```
  return () -> stream.iterator();
  ```
- as `method reference`

  ```
  return stream::iterator;
  ```

---

Complete example:

```
static <T> Iterable<T> select(Iterable<T> it, Predicate<T> pred) {
    return StreamSupport.stream(it.spliterator(), false).filter(pred.negate())::iterator;
}
```

or:

```
static <T> Iterable<T> select(Iterable<T> it, Predicate<T> pred) {
    Stream<T> stream = stream(it.spliterator(), false);
    Predicate<T> negatedPred = pred.negate();
    Stream<T> filteredStream = stream.filter(negatedPred);
    return filteredStream::iterator;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The alternative solution to Holger's I meant in the comment looks like this:

```
static <T> Iterable<T> select(Iterable<T> toIterate, Predicate<T> pred) {
    return () -> new Iterator<T>() {
        Iterator<T> delegate = toIterate.iterator();
        T next = findNextValid();
        public boolean hasNext() {
            return next != null;
        }
        public T next() {
            if (next == null) throw new NoSuchElementException();
            T result = next;
            next = findNextValid();
            return result;
        }
        private T findNextValid() {
            T result = null;
            while (result == null && delegate.hasNext()) {
                T candidate = delegate.next();
                if (pred.test(candidate)) {
                    result = candidate;
                }
            }
            return result;
        }
    };
}
```

The difference is that there's no need for an additional marker for the `hasCurrent`, and it advances the `Iterator` before the next element is actually requested. You might consider the latter to be undesirable though.

Comment: Advancing even before the first element has been queried can be a surprising behavior. But that’s not the reason for the difference regarding the `hasCurrent` field. My solution simply considers the possibility that the source contains `null` elements and the predicate accepts them. The `hasCurrent` flag is there to handle that case correctly. If you preclude `null`, you could replace the field with a `null` test in my solution as well.